# imageresizer resizing a stream - outputting empty stream i.e. 0 bytes

Tags: upload, stream, resize, photo, imageresizer

I'm really struggling to resize (using imeageresizer) a stream created from an image uploaded to an MVC action. A few observations:

- inStream is originally properly defined and contains the image stream with content (length >0)
- outStream length = 0, position = 0 i.e. it's empty.
- The below code works when my dest output is a path to my local hard drive but doesn't work if the dest is a stream (i.e works if I replace outStream with a local path to save the file).
- I have tried using MemoryStream as well instead of stream but no go.

Anyone solved this one?

Here is my code.Any help much appreciated...thx

```
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Stream inStream = file.InputStream;
                Stream outStream = file.InputStream;

                var mySettings = new ResizeSettings
                {
                    MaxWidth = 100,
                    MaxHeight = 100,
                    Format = "JPG"
                };

                ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(inStream, outStream, mySettings);

                //upload outStream to CDN........
            }
        }

        // Return an empty string to signify success
        return Content("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An input (read-only) stream can't be a output (write) stream. You also can't write to the same stream you read from.

This cannot possibly work:

```
            Stream inStream = file.InputStream;
            Stream outStream = file.InputStream;
```

The [MSDN documentation is a good place to start learning about I/O streams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3352a4t.aspx).